# Rest Endpoint is not invoking?

Tags: java, spring, rest, controller, swagger

I wrote an endpoint which is suppose to upload an excel file and read its content. But to my surprise, the very first logger that I have put in this endpoint is not printing. Which basically, means this endpoint is not invoking.

**MyController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/abc/xyz")
@Validated
@Api(basePath = "/abc/xyz", value = "/abc/xyz", produces = "application/json")
public class MyController extends BaseController {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { "multipart/form-data" }, produces = "application/json")
   @ApiOperation(value = "MyController.upload", notes = "Read File")
   @ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(message = "OK", code = 200, response = ResponseEntity.class),
         @ApiResponse(message = "Forbidden", code = 403, response = ResponseEntity.class),
         @ApiResponse(message = "Internal Server Error", code = 500, response = ResponseEntity.class) })
   public List<XlsPojo> upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
      logger.debug("### Calling Upload:"); // NOT PRINTING
      List<XlsPojo> pojos = new ArrayList<XlsPojo>();
      if (!file.isEmpty()) {
         logger.debug("### file: ");
         try {
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file.getInputStream());
            Sheet datatypeSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(1);
            Iterator<Row> iterator = datatypeSheet.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
               Row currentRow = iterator.next();
               if (currentRow.getRowNum() > 0) {
                  XlsPojo record = XlsPojo.getXlsRecords(currentRow);
                  System.out.println("### record: " + record);
                  pojos.add(record);
               }
            }
         } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception " + e);
         }
      }
      return pojos;
   }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name:'poi-ooxml', version:'3.15'
```

Am I missing something in the above code snippet?

**Environment:**

1. Ubuntu 16.04
2. Spring Boot
3. Swagger for documenting REST API's
4. Gradle to build the project.